# displaying images in EasyGUI

Tags: python-2.7, easygui

I have question, please. How to display an image using easyGUI? I searched a lot, but I did not figure out how to do it. I only found this code that displays an image with buttonm and this is not what I want.

```
image = "python_and_check_logo.gif"
msg   = "Do you like this picture?"
choices = ["Yes","No","No opinion"]
reply=buttonbox(msg,image=image,choices=choices)
```

Comment: You should really have 1 question per post...

Comment: Sorry.. I will modify it now.

Answer (score 2):

The image should be in the same directory as that of your source code. Alternatively you can provide complete path to your image variable as well something like image = '/Users/Desktop/python_and_check_logo.gif'.